# What makes sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api (or sqlalchemy) boost the connection time significantly over raw boto3 calls?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, connection, boto3, amazon-rds

While migrating from raw sql queries and boto3 client to sqlalchemy for orm features, I noticed a significant (1-3x longer execution time) time increase during the connection part.

Here's a simple snippet that prints times for the two different methods:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import time

a = time.time()

# First way, only boto3
client = boto3.client('rds-data')
client.execute_statement(
        secretArn=_secret_arn,
        database=_db_name,
        resourceArn=_db_cluster_arn,
        sql='SELECT 1',
        includeResultMetadata=True
    )

b = time.time()

# Second way, with sqlalchemy + sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api (which uses boto3)
rds_engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql+auroradataapi://:@/{0}'.format(_db_name),
    connect_args = dict(
        aurora_cluster_arn = _db_cluster_arn,
        secret_arn = _secret_arn,
        )
    )
rds_engine.execute('SELECT 1')

c= time.time()
print(b-a)
print(c-b)
```

> 2.0279603004455566
> 3.37813138961792

Even with multiple runs averaged, the ratio remains very close. I've found that the `rds_engine.connect()` in the background is the culprit, but there's so much internal stuff that is called that I cannot figure out what causes the big delay.

What makes it that slow, and is it avoidable at all ?